# Diagonals in a non-square matrix - python

Tags: python, matrix

In previous question I found a way to get all the diagonals from a sqare matrix. This is my code:

```
diags=[[s[y-x][x] for x in range(n) if 0<=y-x<n] for y in range(2*n-1)]
```

For example, I have this matrix:

```
m=[[V,A,T],[D,I,S],[O,I,M],[F,U,A]]
```

This is the output I want:

```
[[V],[D,A],[O,I,T],[F,I,S],[U,M],[A]]
```

I already know how to get the diagonals in forward and reverse directions.
The problem is that this code only works for sqare matrix, but now I need to find all the diagonals in a non-square matrix. 
I think the problem is with this part of the code:

```
for y in range(2*n-1)
```

My question is: Is there a way to define diagonals for a non-square matrix? And if there has, would someone help me?
I found nothing that would help me in other questions.
P.S: I'm not allowed to use numpy.
Any form of help, hint, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to include sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a straightforward generalization of your code for a square matrix. Instead of `2*n-1 = n+n-1`, you instead need `m+n-1` in the outer list, and in the inner list, you need to check bounds in both the row and column directions, since they will be different.

```
mat = [['V', 'A', 'T'], ['D', 'I', 'S'], ['O', 'I', 'M'], ['F', 'U', 'A']]
rows = len(mat)
cols = len(mat[0])
diags = [[mat[sum_-k][k]
          for k in range(sum_ + 1)
          if (sum_ - k) < rows and k < cols]
         for sum_ in range(rows + cols - 1)]
print(diags)
```

Result:

```
[
    ['V'],
    ['D', 'A'],
    ['O', 'I', 'T'],
    ['F', 'I', 'S'],
    ['U', 'M'],
    ['A']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code (in c++) will print the diagonals:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char matrix[4][3] = { {'V',  'A',  'T'},
                          {'D',  'I',  'S'},
                          {'O',  'I',  'M'},
                          {'F',  'U',  'A'}};

    int m = 4, n = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < m + n - 1; i++) {      //m+n-1 = 4+3-1 = 6 diagonals   
        int z1 = i < n ? 0 : i - n + 1;
        int z2 = i < m ? 0 : i - m + 1;

        for (int j = i - z2; j >= z1; j--)
                std::cout << matrix[j][i - j] << " ";

        std::cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
V 
D A 
O I T 
F I S 
U M 
A
```